Flutter execution failed for task ':audioplayers_android:parseDebugLocalResources'
I got the problem after installing the audioplayers in my flutter project.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':audioplayers_android:parseDebugLocalResources'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':audioplayers_android:androidApis'.
Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: /Users//Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-33/android.jar.
> /Users//Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-33/android.jar

Everything was fine until installing this package
I'm using AGP ver 7.5, here is my build.gradle:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.flutter_chat_app"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.t1n0o69.popeepapp"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}


I use ./gradlew build --stacktrace  many time to prin stack trace, try up and down the AGP version but not solved yet.
There ís one more problem, I tried installing Java Kit into my Mac M2, I check the version by the command java -version and have got the result:

java version "22.0.1" 2024-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22.0.1+8-16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0.1+8-16, mixed mode, sharing)

I also use the command /usr/libexec/java_home -V and the result is:

Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
22.0.1 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 22.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-22.jdk/Contents/Home
19.0.2 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 19.0.2" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-22.jdk/Contents/Home

So I have 2 Java versions, and the default version is 22.0.1, but when I check in system setting, I can't see the Java logo anywhere, my old macbook mid 2015 can see it. How to config to make it appear in system setting?
My questions seem a bit lengthy, I hope to receive your help. Thanks alot!
